# Proving $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1 + 1/x^2}{1 + 1/x}$ does not exist using the sequence definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working through problems in a real analysis textbook. I don't have any solutions. I am using the following definition for a limit:

**Definition:** Given a function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a limit point $x_{0} \in D$, for a number $\ell$, we write

$$\lim_{x\to x_{0}} f(x) = \ell $$

provided that whenever $\{x_{n}\} \in D - \{x_{0}\}$ that converges to $x_{0}$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_{n}) = \ell.$$

**Problem:**

I am trying to show that the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1 + 1/x^2}{1 + 1/x}$$

does not exist.

**My attempt:**

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence in $D - \{0\}$ that converges to $0$. Now we need to show that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1 + 1/x_{n}^2}{1 + 1/x_{n}} = \ell.$$

Rewrite the limit as follows:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1 + 1/x_{n}^2}{1 + 1/x_{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{x_{n}^{2} + 1}{x_{n}^2 + x_{n}} = \dfrac{1}{0},$$

which is undefined. Thus, we can conclude that our limit does not exist.

Comment: That is correct. You need to judge if your instructors wanted a fuller explanation of the very last equality or that is enough. If that is the case, you can work with arbitrary sequences as you did, but you can also pick a specific one, like $x_n=1/n$ and work with it, since it is enough to show non-existence for one sequence to ensure that the original limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, in order to show in this way the limit doesn't exist we
have to address to a specific sequence. Take for example $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$
which converges to $0$, but

\begin{align*}
f\left(a_{n}\right) & =f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}}}{1+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}}=\frac{1+n^{2}}{1+n}=\frac{\left(1+n\right)^{2}-2n}{1+n}=1+n-\frac{2n}{1+n}=\\
 & =1+n-\frac{2\left(1+n\right)-2}{1+n}=-1+n+\frac{2}{1+n}\to\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: You don't "have to", rather "it is enough". The argument for a general sequence can also be completed.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $x_n=1/n$ converges to $0$; on the other hand,
$$
f(1/n)=\frac{1+n^2}{1+n}>\frac{n^2}{2n}=\frac{n}{2}
$$

Therefore, the sequence $f(1/n)$ doesn't converge.